# Command not found after installing successfully via pip

Tags: python, youtube, pip

I just downloaded `youtube-dl` via pip as follows:

```
sukhvir@SN:~$ sudo pip install youtube-dl
Downloading/unpacking youtube-dl
  Downloading youtube_dl-2015.06.25-py2.py3-none-any.whl (965kB): 965kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: youtube-dl
Successfully installed youtube-dl
Cleaning up...
```

then when i try to run it, the following error shows up:

```
sukhvir@SN:~$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcIy9NiNbmo
-bash: youtube-dl: command not found
```

Can you please help as to why this is happening and how can i rectify this issue ?

Comment: It's a python module so maybe try running it inside the python shell?

Comment: its funny .. i am able to run it if i install it using easy_install .. but not if I do it using pip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it is a bit old, but I ran in the same problem.

The solution is simple: you installed it  with 'sudo' rights,
so if you run it with `sudo youtube-dl` will start without problem (as module).

To avoid this, you could install `pip install --user youtube-dl`